# how to convert the encrypted 256 bits into its 20 digit representation

Tags: encoding, character-encoding, cryptography

the requirement is to convert the cipher text output of an algorithm to a 15 to 20 digit number representation.

the output must be converted to a numeric representation  to convert it to an 15-20 digit OTP

Comment: what is your problem? What part give you troubles? We do not solve homeworks for you, but we can help on the part you do no understand.

Comment: If i needed to convert it to a characters i would just divide it by 8 and get 32 bytes so to each byte i would assign a character using ascii. but the part i dont understand is how to convert the 256 bits data to a 20 digit number and get back the same 256 bits data

Comment: @jpn just hash it with `sha-1`. it creates 20-bit result.

Comment: "numeric representation" usually means a string with decimal numbers. So convert it to base 10, and then to characters '0' - '9'

Comment: @Afshin No, SHA-1 creates a 20 **byte** hash, not bit.

Comment: "how to convert the 256 bits data to a 20 digit number and get back the same 256 bits data". If, by 'digit', you mean a decimal digit, then the answer is simple: it **can't** be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a OTP it generally is not necessary to convert it back, it can be computed on each side and the result compared. Loss of precision is acceptable.

256-bits can not be completely represented in 20 digits in such a manor that it can be converted back. 256 bits is 2^256 which is ~10^76, 20 digits is 10^20 and thus is to small to contain 256 bits.